# unable to populate data of table inside ContentPlaceHolder in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to populate the data of a table inside ContentPlaceHolder, but its not populating. Earlier i tried the same code in another aspx page with body tag and its populating there.Here i cant place body tag in ContentPlaceHolder.Here i am sending the request to the web api to get the data and i am getting the data in JSON format. I am not sure,But i feel that something is going bad with ContentPlaceHolder.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/RLCS_Connect/TLConnect_New.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ShowNoOfLocations.aspx.cs" Inherits="TLConnect_Staffing.RLCS_Connect.ShowNoOfLocations" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <div>  
        <h2><b>Location Table:</b></h2>  
        <table id="Location" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="2" width="600px">  
            <tr>  
                <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">Cl_stateid</td>  
                <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">SM_Name</td>  
                <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">CL_CityID</td>  
                <td style="background-color: gray; color:white">LM_Name</td>  
                <td style="background-color: gray; color:white">CL_BranchName</td>  
                <td style="background-color: gray; color:white">CL_BranchAddress</td> 
                <td style="background-color: gray; color:white">CL_OfficeType</td> 
                <td style="background-color: gray; color:white">CL_EstablishmentType</td> 
            </tr>  
        </table>  
    </div>  
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HFClientId" runat="server" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var uri = 'http://localhost:62983/api/ClientDetail/NoOfLocations';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var id = $('#HFClientId').val();
            $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
            .done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    $('#Location').append("<tr><td>" + item.Cl_stateid + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.SM_Name + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.CL_CityID + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.LM_Name + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.CL_BranchName +
                        "<td>" + item.CL_BranchAddress + "<td>" + item.CL_OfficeType + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.CL_EstablishmentType + "</td></tr>");
                });
            });
        });

    </script>  
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Are you getting response back?

Comment: I feel that the script section is not executing. I have placed breakpoint there in the script but its not hitting. I have tried the same thing in another page with body tag and it was working fine there.

Comment: Use Developer tools of IE, Chrome or Firefox and find out the ID of control, may be you are not targeting  to exact element. Also try by placing this script in external js file and add the reference in your page.

Comment: You probably need to use `var id = $('#<%= HFClientId.ClientID  %>').val();`. Something you would have seen when looking at the generated html that aspnet renames the ID of the Control client side.